# GoogleAuthIOException when using Google Cloud Endpoints with Authentication

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints, google-authentication

I am trying to send an authenticated message to my backend and just get the following error. 
I followed the tutorial in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android#calling_the_backend_api without luck. If I use the Web API it works fine, but it fails from the android client. Any idea of why this problem? Thanks.

04-08 22:51:27.385: W/GLSUser(13215): GoogleAccountDataService.getToken()

04-08 22:51:27.395: W/GLSActivity(13215): [apc] Status from wire: BadUsername status: BAD_USERNAME

04-08 22:51:27.400: W/System.err(8964): com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException